# Calculating bearing of a line

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line, geometry, fields-attributes, bearing

When the bearing of a line is calculated using the "Add Geometry Attribute (LINE_BEARING)" tool, is the bearing referenced to Grid North or True North?

Comment: Which software are you working with?

Comment: ESRI ArcGIS Desktop